# Interior exterior and the boundary of a set in X with respect to cofinite topological space

Tags: general-topology

The question is to find the interior and the exterior and the boundary of  the set  $A=[0,1)$ with respect to the cofinite topological space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what $X$ (the total space) is. If $X=[0,1]$, then $A$ is itself open, being cofinite ($X\setminus A=\{1\}$). Then the interior is $A$, and the exterior is $\emptyset$ (as $A$ is dense).

If $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A$ has empty interior, as it cannot contain a cofinite set and $A$ is dense because it's not finite nor $X$, making the exterior empty too.

Comment: X is the set of real numbers R  thank you I understand

Answer (score 0):

Let A be a subset of a cofinite space S.

If A is cofinite, the interior of A is A,
the closure of A is S,
the boundary of A is S - A.
As the complement of A is finite, the exterior empty.

If A is not cofinite, then the interior is empty,
If A is infinite, then the closure of A is S,
. . the boundary of A is S and the exterior of A is empty.
If A is finite, then the closure of A is A,
. . the boundary of A is A and the exterior of A is S - A.

As you did not stipulate within what space [0,1) is a subset, I leave to you to apply the above.

Exercise.  If [0,1) is a subset of [0,1] with the cofinite topology, what is the interior, closure, boundary and exterior of [0,1)?

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful in  the exercise I think that the boundary is X= [0,1] because it intersects the interior  [0,1) and the exterior phi  for all x correct me if I am wrong